# Which Win API does QtSerialPort use?

Tags: qt, usb, libusb, cdc, qtserialport

There are servral USB libraries out there. I have tried libusb and it won't work for me. I cannot connect my USB device with that library because my driver for that USB device is using `usbser.sys` driver. My USB device is a Communication Device Class (CDC).

The only USB library that works for me is `QtSerialPort` (I have not tested Win32 API yet) and now to the question: If `QtSerialPort` only works for my USB device, what API does `QtSerialPort` use then? Does `QtSerialPort` use internal Win32 API functions, or own internal API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, QtSerialPort uses the Windows API to communicate with serial ports (CreateFile, WriteFile, ReadFile, SetCommTimeouts, etc.).

You can read the relevant source code here:

https://github.com/qt/qtserialport/blob/dev/src/serialport/qserialport_win.cpp